# Why does my private network transaction use a different amount of gas than my mainnet transaction performed immediately after?

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, ganache, gas-estimate, forks

I am forking the mainnet from my own `geth` node with `ganache-cli --fork` option. Immediately after the fork, I simulate a transaction to a contract on the forked, private network. I then immediately send that same exact transaction on the mainnet. These are the same transactions from the same account with the same nonce.

After the transactions are processed, I am finding that the `gas_used` on the mainnet is ~1% (or less) different than the `gas_used` on the ganache fork. How can this be if I simply forked the network and sent two equivalent contract transactions? Can it have something to do with the `solc` compiler versions?

Comment: There are optimizations done on the solc all the time but difficult to say if that's the real reason.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen What additional information would help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much ideas currently and I'm not too familiar with solc so can't help you much further. Hopefully someone else can give you a better answer.